# How to estimate parameters of exponential functions?

Tags: exponential-function, estimation, parameter-estimation

I am a new bird to math! I have an expression as follows,
$$e^{-ux}+e^{-uy}=z$$
I have at least  ten pairs of $(x,y,z)$, so how can I estimate the value of $u$? And how to **evaluate** my results?

Hand computation really bothers me. Can anybody give some suggestions in details?

Comment: You could make Wolfram Alpha do it for you. Here's the computation when $x=5$, $y=6$, and $z=7$: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+e%5E%28-5u%29%2Be%5E%28-6u%29%3D7++for+u

Comment: @BillCook, Thanks a lot! This tool is so cool. However, how could I evaluate my results?